# Java enum can I add a return method?

Tags: java, android, enums

Is it possible to use Enum in Android like this?

```
public enum EventAction 
{
  SDCARD_MOUNTED
  {
    public String toString() {
      return "External SDCard was mounted";
    }

    public int getCode() {
      return 25;
    }
  }
}
```

From the outside code I have an access only to EventAction.SDCARD_MOUNTED.toString() but .getCode() is not visible. Examples I saw show how getCode() is used from inside code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declare `getCode()` as an `abstract` method:

```
public enum EventAction 
{
  SDCARD_MOUNTED
  {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "External SDCard was mounted";
    }
    @Override
    public int getCode() {
      return 25;
    }
  };

  public abstract int getCode();

}
```

If every value is going to be implemented the same way, it's clearer to do this:

```
public enum EventAction {
  SDCARD_MOUNTED(25, "External SDCard was mounted");
  private final int code;
  private final String message;
  private EventAction(int code, String message) {
    this.code = code;
    this.message = message;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() { return message; }
  public int getCode() { return code; }
}
```

Comment: Great, clean example. I implemented in a common way for many values like you showed.

Answer (score 5):

You need declare the method at the enum level :

```
public enum EventAction 
{
  SDCARD_MOUNTED
  {
    public String toString() {
      return "External SDCard was mounted";
    }

    public int getCode() {
      return 25;
    }
  };

  public abstract int getCode();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public enum EventAction 
{
  SDCARD_MOUNTED("External SDCard was mounted",25),
  SDCARD_MOUNTED_1("External SDCard was mounted 111111111",50);

  private String details;
  private int code;

  private EventAction(String details,int code){
      this.code = code;
      this.details = details;
  }

    public String toString() {
      return this.details;
    }

    public int getCode() {
      return this.code;
    }
}
```

in main

```
System.out.println(EventAction.SDCARD_MOUNTED.toString());
System.out.println(EventAction.SDCARD_MOUNTED.getCode());
```

OUTPUT:

```
External SDCard was mounted
25
External SDCard was mounted 111111111
50
```

Comment: This doesn't allow different properties for other enumerated values.

Comment: @Maxim it is actually a little different. Note the location of the semi-colon (`;`) It makes these methods members of *every* `EventAction`, rather than just the `SDCARD_MOUNTED` value as in your question.

Comment: It allows for all the properties, here it was hard coded thats all... the semicolon terminate the properties and make the other method common to all properties.

Comment: It is a running code. I have executed and then only pasted here.

Comment: Thanks dku.rajkumar, now it looks exactly like @erickson showed. This way it works.

Comment: Now your answer is an isomorphic copy of mine.